# Embed Facebook video via ajax - Resize Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, video

For a video gallery, I'm using AJAX to load videos from different video hosts like FB, Youtube, Vimeo etc. I'm embedding the FB video like as mentioned in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player using FB's JS SDK.

The problem is that when I'm requesting the FB video via AJAX **the video is resizing to a smaller dimension** like this: [image]

No issues when the page is fully reloaded(without AJAX).

**The JS snippet:**

```
$.ajax({
                url: "index.php?gallery&type=fbVideoCode&url=" + url,
                success: function(response) {
                    response = $.trim(response);
                    $('span.carousel').replaceWith(response);
                    FB.XFBML.parse(); // To re-parse all FB videos on the page
                }
            });
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with a CSS of a carousel that I was using.

Posting the FB video code for others :-)

**PHP:** (used for AJAX requests)

```
function getFBEmbedPlayer($video_id, $width = 600) {
        return "<div class=\"fb-video\" data-href=\"https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=$video_id\" data-width=\"$width\">
    <div class = \"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\"></div></div>";
    }
```

**JS:**

Follow the instructions in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player

Answer (score 0):

This will make all videos from Youtube and Vimeo responsive:

```
// Find all YouTube videos
            var $allVideos = $("iframe[src^='//player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src^='//www.youtube.com']"),

    // The element that is fluid width
    $fluidEl = $("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

    $(this)
    .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

    // and remove the hard coded width/height
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {

    var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

  // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
    .width(newWidth)
    .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

Taken from [Chris Coyiers tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

Comment: The issue was with a CSS of a carousel. Thank you for giving me the idea about the browser resizing. I was just meddling with the JS alone in my IDE, my folly